# How replace None with empty string in Tornado template

Tags: templates, tornado, nonetype

I have some models from SQL-Alchemy passing to `generate` function:

```
from tornado import template
loader = template.Loader('.')
template = loader.load('index.html')
content = template.generate(user=user)
```

index.html:

```
<div>Name:<span>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} </span></div>
```

My problem is displaying `None` for null values in the user object. If the number of objects and fields were low, I could use `or ''` for each variable:

```
    <div>Name:<span>{{ user.first_name or ''}} {{ user.last_name or ''}} </span></div>
```

But there are more than 40 fields inside 6 objects in some HTML files. I'm looking for a way to tell the template engine to replace all null values to ''

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell the template engine to replace every `None` value with empty string. I don't think other template engines have this feature either.

My approach will be to display the fields using a for-loop:

Handler:

```py
class MyHandler(...):
    fields = [field.name for field in user.__table__.columns]
    content = template.generate(user=user, fields=fields)
```

Template:

```html
{% for field in fields %}
    {{ getattr(user, field) or '' }}
{% end %}
```

---

**Bonus answer**

In my projects, I create a utility function to handle how variables are displayed in the templates, such as converting `None` to `''` or formatting `datetime` objects, or calling the variable if it's a callable.

```py
def get_value(variable):
    if variable == None:
        return ''
    elif isinstance(variable, datetime):
        return variable.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    elif callable(variable):
        return get_value(variable())
    # more conditions ...
    # such as replace True/False booleans with Yes/No
```

Then pass this function to the templates from your base handler's [`get_template_namespace`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_template_namespace) function.

Finally, in the templates, just call this function for every variable:

```html
{% for field in fields %}
    {{ get_value(getattr(user, field)) }}
{% end %}
```

If a field returns a date, `get_value` will format it, if the field returns `None`, it will replace it with `''`, and if the field a callable method, it will be called.

Comment: Thanks. I preferred the bonus answer!